# How to get data from dynamically generated element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to do something with data from dynamically generated element, like printing the data from the clicked element, how can I do that?

here's my jquery code:

```
let setHistory = () => {
   $('#transaction-history').empty();
    transactionHistory.forEach((o) => {
        var htmlBlock = "";
        htmlBlock += `<div class="btn btn-outline transaction-history-item d-flex flex-column justify-content-center mr-4">`
            + `<img class="transaction-history-item-image card pl-2 pr-2 pt-1 pb-1 mx-auto" src="../assets/placeholder-image.png" alt="" >`
            + `<div class="transaction-history-number mt-1 mx-auto">${o.meterNumber}</div>`
            + `<div class="transaction-history-value mx-auto" data-value=${o.value}>Rp${o.value.toLocaleString().replaceAll(',','.')}</div>`
            + `</div>`;
        $('#transaction-history').append(htmlBlock);
    });
}
```

and the transactionHistory data looks like this:

```
 let transactionHistory = [
    {
        meterNumber: "1234152322",
        value: 250000
    },
    {
        meterNumber: "1115648463",
        value: 50000
    }
]
```

and here's the illustration of the dynamically generated element:
[image]

Basically, I want to get the meterNumber and value from the card I clicked, how can I implement that?

Comment: Here's how to create an element instead, then assign a click handler to it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yzej7aw8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can get desired data by using [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/#next-selector) selector or [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) jQuery functions.

[image: Codepen example]

using `next()` function :

```
$(document).on('click', '.transaction-history-item-image', function() {

    var tranNumber = $(this).next().html();
    var tranValue = $(this).next().next().html();

});
```

---

or by using `parent()` and `find()` :

```
$(document).on('click', '.transaction-history-item-image', function() {

    var tranNumber = $(this).parent().find('.transaction-history-number').html();
    var tranValue = $(this).parent().find('.transaction-history-value').html();

});
```